# ReactNative case sensitivity ignored when sending custom headers through fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header-files

I am using react native 0.23.1 (also tried it using 29) on Mac. during a fetch request react ios, when I send a custom header (eg 'Api-Version' : '0.1' ) the server receives it all in lower case ('api-version':'0.1').The standard of writing a header is using camel case, I don't have control over the server code so the request fails as it is expecting the headers in camelcase.When checking the server log found out that all the other non custom headers come as camel case while only the custom headers come as all lowercase.

I tried using different http clients such as frisbee and axios still it was the same.

Doing the same request using a chrome console was successful.

Following is my fetch code

```
  fetch(Properties.uris.base + Properties.uris.getBusinessDetails.replace("{businessId}",   Properties.appId).replace("{timezone",this.getTimeZone()), {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': DeviceInfo.getUserAgent(),
            'X-UserId':userDetailsJson.username,
            'X-BusinessId':Properties.appId,
            'X-App-Version': DeviceInfo.getVersion(),
            'Api-Version': Properties.fetchHeaderInformation.apiVersion,
        }})
        .then((response) => response.json())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fork the fetch repo from [github](https://github.com/github/fetch) and did my alteration, then used it on the react native project